# what is the "main" function equivalent in visual c++ (windows form application)?

Tags: visual-c++, cursor

i have code for getting cursor position in visual c++ (windows form application).
But how do i display it? I used labels but it does not give me a continuously changing cursor position. 
My main question is in normal c++ program i wrote the infinite while loop code in "main" function. where do i write it in visual c++ (windows form application) code?

```
if (!GetCursorPos(&point)) {
    this->label4->Text = "An error occurred: ";
    //cout << GetLastError();
} else {
    x = point.x;
    y = point.y;
}
Sleep(1000);
//system("cls");
this->label3->Text = Convert::ToString(x);
this->label4-> Text=Convert::ToString(y);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you could use the event system of forms. There should be an event that is fired when the cursor changes it's position. Then you could implement an event handler to update your labels.

Comment: @lupz i am trying to display cursor position in runtime. i have a code for it in c++, but unable to do so in vc++. i get only one position and not continuously.

Comment: What cursor do you mean? Do you open a file and refer to the read/write cursor? Do you mean the mouse position on forms component? Do you mean a text cursor in a forms component? Some small code snippet would help to understand what you do.

Comment: @lupz i am talking about the mouse position.

Comment: if(!GetCursorPos(&point))
     {
     this->label4-> Text= "An error occurred: ";
      //cout << GetLastError();
     }
     else
     {
      x = point.x;
      y = point.y;
     }
    Sleep(1000);
    //system("cls");
    this->label3-> Text=Convert::ToString(x);
    this->label4-> Text=Convert::ToString(y);

hope u understand it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an infinite loop to get the cursor position and update the labels, forms offers an event system. So you could figure out the cursor position and update the labels every time, the mouse moves within your application through the mouse move event.

See [Control::MouseMove Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) for documentation and some examples.

Comment: @lupz- thanks a lot. :). i am sorry my question was not that clear enough, i am good at c++ but new to vc++ so do not know much about these events and all. If you suggest me a good book on vc++ that would be great (i noe the c++ coding stuff )

Comment: You're welcome. It's a while ago, when I was actively developing with forms and .Net. I remember that I was in the same situation when I started :). It seemed like a jungle of concepts and conventions to me. Usually the [MSDN Libary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) features a good documentation to get started and can be used as a machete to get through that jungle. There are many books and resources. I'll bet you find suggestions on SO, too (I never read a (whole) book on this, sry).